# Unsure about the logic of the code

Tags: java

I cant test my method's code manually yet as Im not done with other associated code yet, but I feel like the logic of the method `public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col)` is wrong. The method returns `true` if the shape has a filled block (any `char`) at the given row/col position and `false` if the block is empty(the dot `'.'`). If the position is out of bounds, raise a `FitItException` with an informative message. Could smb please look through it and let me know if anything is wrong with the method's code? Thanks!

```
public class CreateShape {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private char dc;
    private Rotation initialPos;
    private char[][] shape = new char[height][width]; 
public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col) 
    {
        if(row < 0 || row >= height || col < 0 || col >= width)
            throw new FitItException("Oops! Out of bounds!");
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < shape.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < shape[i].length; j++) {
                    if (shape[row][col] == dc)
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: do you need to iterate?

Comment: :) :), could not think simply! @PrashantGhimire Thank you, Im gonna change that right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col) {
    if(row < 0 || row >= height || col < 0 || col >= width)
        throw new FitItException("Oops! Out of bounds!");
    else 
        return (shape[row][col] == dc);
}
```

does the same as your code currently does. I'm not sure what you are going through the array for, you're not even using the `i` and `j` variables.